# Haxe add or remove item during iteration

Tags: list, iteration, addition, haxe

It is okay to add and remove items from a list while iterating it in Haxe? Or can it create a weird behaviour ?
I'm suspicious, because it was totally forbidden to do so in C#.

archip

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It does not end well.. you can iterate the array and remove elements tho:

```
var i:Int = 0;      
while (i < array.length) {
    i++;
    if (removeCondition) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

*Edit* if you are using Lists the method should be similar, haven't done it with lists so far.

Comment: **Warning**: As mentioned below in Mihail's answer below, this skips the first element in the array. Use Mihail's code

Answer (score 7):

Answer marked as correct is skiping the first element.
Correct code will be:

```
var i:Int = 0;      
while (i < array.length) {
    if (removeCondition) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    } else i++;
}
```

Also, if you don't mind reverse iteration:

```
var i = array.length;
while (i-- > 0) 
   if (removeCondition) 
      array.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: Updated with one more option to go